# Vue.js class is not instantiated

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a class named `Artefact` which contains a component `AddArtefact`. But the Instance Lifecycle Hooks (mounted, created...) are not called in the `AddArtefact` class and if you print `this` it shows `null`. But why is this?

[image]

**Artefact**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button v-show="selectedTab === 0" @click="AddArtefact">Add Artefact</button>
        <AddArtefact v-show="selectedTab === 1"></AddArtefact>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Vue, Prop, Component} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import $ from 'jquery';
import AddArtefact from '@/views/add/AddArtefact.vue';

@Component({
    components: {
        AddArtefact,
    },
})

export default class Artefact extends Vue {
    private selectedTab: number = 0;

    private AddArtefact() {
        this.selectTab(1);
    }

    private selectTab(tab: number) {
        this.selectedTab = tab;
    }
}
</script>
```

**AddArtefact**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{Test}}</p>
        <button @click="testClick">Test Button</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Vue, Component, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class AddArtefact extends Vue {
    private Test: string = '';

    private mounted() { 
        this.Test = 'Test 123';
        console.log('test');
    }

    private testClick() {
        console.log('Test Click');
        console.log(this); 
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `@Component`:

```
@Component
export default class AddArtefact extends Vue {
```

And you can put the mounted in there too:

```
@Component({
   mounted(this: AddArtefact) {
     ...
   }
}) 
export default class AddArtefact extends Vue {
```